# Accessing Nested repeaters

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

Greeting, I'll try to make this short and clear

I have a NumericTextBox and a Button, upon pressing the Button it tells repeater **A** how many times should it repeat based on the value introduced on the NumericTextBox:

```
    protected void ButtonRepeaterA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string x = RadNumericTextBoxRepeatsOnA.Text.Trim();
        int y = Convert.ToInt32(x);

        int[] RowCount = new int[y];
        RepeaterA.DataSource = RowCount;
        RepeaterA.DataBind();

        int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;

        for (int i = currentYear; i <= currentYear + 100; i++)
        {
            //DropDownCCYear.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString()));

            foreach (RepeaterItem item in RepeaterA.Items)
            {
                RadComboBox DropDownCCYear = (RadComboBox)item.FindControl("DropDownCCYear");
                DropDownCCYear.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString()));
            }
        }


    }
```

The issue arises with repeater **B**, which is inside repeater **A**

It behaves similarly to repeater **A**, but I only want the button presses to affect the repeater in which the button is inside, so it won't clear the data introduced on the controls inside the other repetitions of repeater **B**, which is what happens if i use a "foreach repeater" as follows:

```
    protected void ButtonRepeaterB(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (RepeaterItem item in RepeaterA.Items)
        {
            Repeater RepeaterB = (Repeater)item.FindControl("RepeaterB");
            RadNumericTextBox RadNumericTextBoxRepeatsOnB = (RadNumericTextBox)item.FindControl("RadNumericTextBoxRepeatsOnB");

            string x = RadNumericTextBoxRepeatsOnB.Text.Trim();
            int y = Convert.ToInt32(x);

            int[] RowCount = new int[y];
            RepeaterB.DataSource = RowCount;
            RepeaterB.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Is there a "forthis repeater"-like function?
any ideas how i can approach this?

Answer (score 0):

`Repeater`s have an `ItemCommand` event that I think would be useful for you.  When the `Button`'s `Click` event happens, the `ItemCommand` event will swallow it up if you haven't set the `Button`'s `Click` event handler.

On the `ItemCommand` event you can use the `e` arguments to determine which button, and the `sender` to determine which `Repeater` it came from.

I was a little confused by your question, but I think this is the answer you're driving to.  Does that help?